# How to automatically close mysql connection in ServiceStack ormlite

Tags: mysql, connection, servicestack

I used ServiceStack OrmLite to access AWS MySQL , when a API request returned the data. There are lots of MySql connections in sleep state.

How to close those db connections when ending a request ?

`public object Get(GetCustomer request) 
{ 
   return Db.SingleById<Customer>(request.Id); 
}`

I hosted API in IIS.

ServiceStack and ServiceStack.OrmLite is 4.0.56

MySQL is from AWS RDS, database engine version is 5.6.21

MySQL.Data is 6.9.8

Comment: Could you provide the code showing how you are using OrmLite? Eg, from a `Service` via `Db` property or via `IDbConnectionFactory` etc.

Comment: I used Db property from Service. like this:
 `public object Get(GetCustomer request)
    {
        return Db.SingleById<Customer>(request.Id);
    }
` . I hosted API in `IIS`.

Comment: Can you also provide what version of ServiceStack you are using as well as what version of MySql you are connecting too? Update the question is probably the easiest way.

Comment: DB connections should already be disposed of at the end of every request. What's your connection string look like (without password), you may have connection pooling enabled or something.

Comment: I know with my MSSQL connection, I had connection pooling and kept on getting connection failures because each new request was holding onto a connection, and the pool filled up.  While the `Service.Dispose` base implementation inside ServiceStack does check and dispose the `Db` connection, I wasn't guaranteed when that would occur (GC collection).  I ended up implementing `OnPostExecuteServiceFilter` in my AppHost to forcibly close the DB connection earlier and prevent DB connection errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason. I register some interface without scope. the correct method is:

`container.RegisterAutoWiredType(x, ReuseScope.Request)`

Default reuse scope is `ReuseScope.None`.